# How to allow some User only access his own data in endpoint in Spring Boot / Spring Security with pagination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, pagination

I have a question related to the limiting of the products list to specific User in my application. Ive got an API: "/api/v1/{userId}/products" and I want to use pagination in my UserRestController which I have already used in AdminRestController:

```
@GetMapping
    public Response<Page<Product>> getProductPage(@PageableDefault(sort = "id") Pageable pageable) {
        return Response.ok(productService.findAll(pageable));
    }
```

I have read some threads and find some solutions with "@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.principal.id")". Now, I want to implement pagination in my endpoint in UserRestController which should return only the products list related to the specific User (not the list of all products). I have tried to use the following:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/{userId}/products")
@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.principal.id")
public Response<Page<Product>> getProductPage(@PageableDefault(sort = "id") Pageable pageable) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return Response.ok(productService.findAll(pageable));
}
```

But I have got the access problem, could you help me to figure out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already implemented into `Spring-Secutiry` and `Spring-Data`.

In config, you need to add a @Bean to provide your `principal` into the queriing :

```
@Configuration
public class Conf{
    // `principal` provider for the Spring-Data JPQL requests
    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
      return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

After that you'll be abble to write things like that :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "datas", exported = true)
public interface DataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Data, Long> {

  @Override
  @Query(value = "Select d From Data d Where d.ownerId = ?#{principal?.username}")
  Page<Data> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Also, read the official doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/integrations/data.html

Comment: Thanks for the information!
I have already added @Bean, now I want to link my service layer with repository.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `now I want to link my service layer with repository` ?

Comment: I mean that I have the following logic: I have controller and SecurityConfig with necessary methods, but I still cannot choose products only related to current user (not all the list). I have created in my service layer additional method which accept Long userId & Pageable pageable and I method in repository layer which there is a SQL query with choosing the products.

Comment: I just gave you the solution to write a repository that select data using the current user to filter the data.